# postgres create unique row in table

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I use Postgres.

I have a table like this and I understand that i can't create a unique index with more than 1 null column.

How do I create the table so that if I insert 2 times obj like this it will filed:

```json
{
  content_details_id: 1,
  topic_id: 1,
  subject_id: null,
  chapter_id: null, 
  sub_chapter_id: null,
  learning_unit_id: null, 
  points: null 
}
```

```sql
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS content_details_connections(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     content_details_id INT REFERENCES content_details(id) on update no action on delete cascade NOT 
     NULL,
     topic_id INT REFERENCES topics(id) on update no action on delete cascade,
     subject_id INT REFERENCES subjects(id) on update no action on delete cascade,
     chapter_id INT REFERENCES chapters(id) on update no action on delete cascade,
     sub_chapter_id INT REFERENCES sub_chapters(id) on update no action on delete cascade,
     learning_unit_id INT REFERENCES learning_unit(id) on update no action on delete cascade,
     points INT,
     created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()::TIMESTAMP,
     last_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()::TIMESTAMP,            
     UNIQUE(content_details_id,topic_id,subject_id,chapter_id,sub_chapter_id,learning_unit_id,points))
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `NOW()::TIMESTAMP` is the same as `localtimestamp`

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON content_details_connections (
   content_details_id,
   coalesce(topic_id, -1),
   coalesce(subject_id, -1),
   coalesce(chapter_id, -1),
   coalesce(sub_chapter_id, -1),
   coalesce(learning_unit_id, -1),
   coalesce(points, -1)
);
```

This assumes that -1 is a value that does not occur in the table.